# Dividing in excel by looking up another value

Tags: excel

Looking to create a formula in excel that will divide a cell value by the last time a certain value had a once next to it:

```
A             B     C
20/04/2015  1.68    0
17/04/2015  1.68    0
16/04/2015  1.72    1
15/04/2015  1.66    0
```

So ideally it would be something that took 1.68 and divided it by 1.72, and it found 1.72 because of the 1 adjacent to it in column C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in cell `C2` then drag it to the bottom. `=IF(C3=1,B2/B3,"")`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find the last value in column B that has a `1` next to it, you can use this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(C:C=1),B:B)
```

So for the division, you could do something like:

```
=B1/LOOKUP(2,1/(C:C=1),B:B)
```